# Gravitational imaging

Tags: general-relativity

[Gravitational Imaging](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/defence/12201086/MoD-gravity-sensor-breakthrough-to-see-underground-or-through-walls.html)  So as we know from the famous theory and equations of Einstein is it possible to track the individual gravitational pull?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@anna v has answered the question, but some history can be added.

"[Modern gravity exploration](http://www.ipgp.fr/~diament/Imageries%20Gravi-Mag/Nabighian-et%20al_Gravi.pdf) began during the first third of the twentieth century and continues to this day as a small but important element in current exploration programs ... The first geophysical oil and gas discovery,
the Nash dome in coastal Texas, was the result of a torsion balance survey (LaFehr, 1980). A historical outline of the early development of the gravity method of exploration, from pendulums to torsion balances to gravimeters, is given by Eckhardt (1940)."

The [gravitational torsion balance](http://www.elgi.hu/museum/tinga_.htm) was invented by [Eötvös](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E%C3%B6tv%C3%B6s_experiment), starting about 1885, and has been improved many times.

Comment: Oh , how can one easly say that newtonian variant of gravity is enought if it has no consistent accuracy and that is why Enstein had his claims about the nature ?

Comment: General Relativity is only required near massive bodies, or at very high speeds,  or for cosmological times and distances.  Remember that as the conditions are relaxed, Newtonian gravity is recovered, which is certainly good enough for most engineering applications.

Comment: And with the Newtonian gravity the equetions are linear so that means in principle thah you cannot distinguish between two vector sums giving the same vector result !

Comment: And you cannot distinguish individual pulls since all the gravity fields are constantly merging into one combined field

Comment: That's why they measure gradients, which naturally provide a direction.  In any case, you can always take multiple measurements from different locations ... which is what is done in the practical world.

Comment: So to get the exaclty right answer of 3 d mass distribution you need full shell around the globe taping changes from any directions

Answer (score 5):

It is an interesting link you provide, but it has nothing to do with General Relativity and the stress energy tensor except in a general way, that all gravitational interactions could be modeled with the mathematics of general relativity. For the device one just needs newtonian gravitation, as this map:

[image: gravitational field of the earth]

> Earth's gravity measured by NASA GRACE mission, showing deviations from the theoretical gravity of an idealized smooth Earth, the so-called earth ellipsoid. Red shows the areas where gravity is stronger than the smooth, standard value, and blue reveals areas where gravity is weaker

In the [link](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/defence/12201086/MoD-gravity-sensor-breakthrough-to-see-underground-or-through-walls.html) you gave, similar measurements to much greater accuracy are claimed, the accuracy due to the quantum effects of atomic nature, (not quantum gravitational):

> Neil Stansfield, of the Defence Science and Technology Laboratory, said the new quantum gravity detector works by using lasers to freeze atoms in position and then measuring how the tiny particles are affected by the gravitational pull of nearby objects.
>
> By studying how the particles are influenced by the mass of nearby objects, scientists can then draw a 3D map highlighting how density changes nearby.

This is similar to the [gravitational map](http://www.nasa.gov/audience/foreducators/k-4/features/F_Measuring_Gravity_With_Grace.html) of the earth shown above, but hopefully extremely more accurate.

Comment: You could mention that the radial matter distribution can not be measured, only the angular moments.

Comment: @CuriousOne do you have a lin for that? in the blurb they are talking of 3D,  and that means depth. They would have to have two or more measurements  to get the depth( like bubble chamber measurements need two views :) ).

Comment: Gravitational measurements are restricted by the shell theorem, there is no getting around that... unless NASA has found a way to fly satellites inside the Earth now? Having said that, the consequences for the restrictions on the actual data are not trivial, and to compare them to a bubble chamber is profoundly false. The reconstruction of this data requires sophisticated inverse methods, while tracking data in most 3d hep detectors is a direct measurement (except for Cherenkov detectors).

Comment: @CuriousOne It's actually even worse than that. One can construct perfectly reasonable mass distributions with vastly different angular components that agree exactly as far as any external probe can tell. Gravitational mapping is very underdetermined, and assumptions about the smoothness of the distribution not only help clean up noise, but also are needed to make the inverse problem have an even remotely unique solution.

Comment: @ChrisWhite: I am not surprised... I did the exercise once for 2d electrostatic charge distributions which were reasonable well known (it was for a beam profile measurement and I was admittedly naive about the inclusion of information from other data) and I strongly suspect that the problem doesn't get any better in 3d.

Comment: @CuriousOne with the bubble chamber analogy I am saying that one can get different "views" of a three dimensional projection which give extra over determined degrees of freedom that allow for a 3dimensional reconstruction.

Comment: @ChrisWhite with one probe, yes, you have an undertermined problem. One picture of  a three dimensional object cannot give you a three dimensional distribution. Two  at different angles allow 3D reconstruction . Can it not be that with three or more probes of the same volume the distributions will be  constrained enough to give a 3D reconstruction?

Comment: if one reads the link, they foresee the usefulness of this in thirty years, they are testing the principle

Comment: @annav: Please trust Chris and me on this one. These inverse problem do not have a unique solution and they are extremely sensitive to noise. What these guys are doing there is extremely demanding. Nobody said that it doesn't have an application. I have done a simple inverse problem like this myself. Everybody who has been in a CT has been using this kind of reconstruction. All we are saying is that it's not trivial and that one can't reconstruct certain properties because the satellites can't fly inside the planet. That's why the oil guys are drilling and using gravimeters in the holes.

Comment: So when we finally include effects of general relativity we can strongly guess that job gets total mess.For instance the behavior of one of the objects affects the other one and vice verse . The unpredictability becomes verry strong. I include general relativity first because I imagine cosmic scales where we try to spy over aliens with gravity and second because it is better one from both and it is more correct.

Comment: Please,comment about the so called inverse problem in general relativity, can we reconstruct the 3 d stress tensor with corresponding unique matter distribution knowing the einstein metric by measurment ?

Comment: @CuriousOne   the satellite is a macroscopic measurement . They are talking of "using lasers to freeze atoms in position and then measuring how the tiny particles are affected by the gravitational pull of nearby objects. "  satellites have nothing to do with it. I just used the picture to show that gravitational fields are being measured, and the proposed scheme is doing this with a much more accurate tool which has not much to do with general relativity.

Comment: @КоцетоРайчев I am just pointing out that GR is irrelevant as far as the new detector proposed.  As you see there is doubt even on the simple newtonian level. I am an experimental physicist and my theoretical background does not extend to answering this. What curiousone and chriswhite are saying is  that  it is a many to one situation, many mass distributions may give the same  stress energy tensor.

Comment: @annav: How you do this measurement doesn't matter for the inverse reconstruction problem. Please look into the details.